# Android Layout Buttons are overlapping

Tags: xml, android-layout

I have the following xml file; Which 1/3 button seems to be displayed very well placed, but I can't say the same thing for the two buttons that are following it and are supposed to be displayed one after the other.

The button "hull" is perfectly placed but the following two buttons are overlapping with each other and for some reason the scroll view is not kicking in. Any thoughts? The scroll view just stops as far as the screen height goes.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

 android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fillViewport="true"
 >

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:src="@drawable/k" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/hull"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="62dp"
android:text="Hull Lines" />
<Button
android:id="@+id/offsets"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:text="Table of Offsets" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/finishPa"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:text="Keel and Rudder Details" />


</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hull"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/offsets"
            android:text="Hull Lines" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/offsets"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/finishPa"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:text="Table of Offsets" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/finishPa"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:text="Keel and Rudder Details" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```